# Использование ноутбука в качестве второго монитора для ПК

Tags: windows

Всем привет!
Появилась необходимость подключить ноутбук как второй монитор к ПК без Wi-Fi модуля (функция "Проецирование на этот компьютер" соответственно отказывается работать).
Судя по быстрому ресерчу, HDMI порт в ноутбуках не умеет работать на вход, поэтому этот вариант тоже отпадает.

Цель - обеспечить отсутствие видимой задержки при работе, как с полноценным вторым монитором, а также желательно быстрое переключение из режима обычной работы с ноутбуком в режим второго монитора.
Кто-то решал уже такую задачу? Как можно можно реализовать?

И на ПК, и на ноутбуке стоит Win10 Home 19045.2846

Comment: Попробуйте Space Desc, возможно подойдет.
https://www.spacedesk.net/#products

Comment: @Step1709 пробовал, но работает это все очень печально